# SQL distinct query with whole record

Tags: sql

how can I select all records from table where DISTINCT column value,, i want something like this

```
select * from table where DISTINCT col1, col2, col3 and  S_Id = '20';
```

**EDIT**

[1] How can I find the distinct values for 3 columns (`col1, col2, col3`) that have a same value in a column called `S_Id` in my table?

[2] How can then I select all columns & rows from my table where (`col1, col2, col3`) is found in those distinct values? (`SELECT col0, col1, col2, col3, col4, ... col9 FROM table WHERE ???`(where s_id = val))

Comment: Please try to ask an understandable question.

Comment: You can't. Distinct doesn't work that way.

Comment: When you lack words to describe your problem, try to illustrate it with examples: what you have -> what you want to get.

Comment: Try searching with the keywords "select distinct multiple columns".

Comment: You can only achieve this by using a `group by` on the columns that you want to be distinct, which is almost like a `distinct` with the side effect of having some columns either summed, counted or excluded. But that all depends on what you are trying to achieve, explain that for us and we might be able to help you

Comment: I want to fetch all whole rows where 3 columns(col1, col2, col3) values are distinct and sid = 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there are lots of ways of doing what you want. Try this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM FGEHF_DB.dbo.Tbl_Alotee a
JOIN 
(
    SELECT MAX(ID) AS ID
    FROM FGEHF_DB.dbo.Tbl_Alotee
    WHERE Plot_Id = '4117'  -- or other value
    GROUP BY alotee_name, alotee_fname, alotee_cnic
) b
ON a.ID = b.ID
```

I think we are getting closer now.

Comment: [Here](http://postimg.org/image/fjx79mddp/) is query result

Comment: Is that what you wanted to see?

Comment: That does not help me help you. Explain what is on there that you don't want to see or what you think is missing. Be specific.

Comment: i want to fetch whole row record where only alotee_name, alotee_fname, alotee_cnic not repeat, and other column may whatever.. and where Plot_Id = '4117' i.e. Plot_Id may be repeated and other columns may also..

Comment: If that does not work, please show another graphic and say something like 'ID 73 is shows properly, ID 65 should have been excluded because ...'

Comment: [Check This](http://postimg.org/image/5itmh31k1/)

Comment: That edit should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE 
    col1 != col2 AND
    col1 != col3 AND 
    col2 != col3 AND 
    S_Id = '20';
```

Comment: I am fairly certain she/he only wants the distinct to apply to a single column, not the whole row.

Comment: it returns only 3 columns data but i want whole row with distinct col1,col2,col3

Comment: This is a valid attempt at an answer and should not be flagged. It could be improved with additional comments around the code, but otherwise, if you don't like the answer, you should downvote it, not flag it.

Comment: That `WHERE` clause uses 4 columns so all 4 of those columns plus all of the other columns that exist in your table will appear in the selected results. @Niha Mialk, how are you getting only 3 columns in your results when using this command? This answer returns exactly what you want.

Comment: +1 . . . This seems to be *a* correct reading of the question and it works except for `NULL` values (the OP doesn't specify what to do in that case).  I prefer the more standard `<>` to `!=`, but that is a minor quibble.

Comment: I want to fetch whole record where distinct col1, col2, col3 and sid = 2; when i use distinct query it show distinct record of col1,col2,col3 but i want col1,col2,col3,col4,col5

Comment: above query is not working ,, actually im using primary key in table so i want to ignore primary key with distinct and show whole row

Comment: Why is this command not working for you? What are your results? Meaning, show us data or give us an error message!

Comment: here  is my result -- [See This](http://postimg.org/image/tvch92y4d/)

Comment: here  is my result -- new link-- [See This](http://postimg.org/image/eufgybejd/)