# How to select all columns where a set of them are distinct in SQL Server 2008 r2

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2008-r2, distinct

I have a bunch of columns in a sql table and I want insert every field of that table into a temp table where a set of the columns are distinct.  In other words, say I have a table with columns a, b, c, d, e, f, and g.  How could I select every row where a, b, and c are distinct?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? ("SQL" is **not** a DBMS product, it's query language)

Comment: Distinct from what? Eachother or as compared to all other rows?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "distinct": chances are the `distinct` keyword, a proper `group by` statement, or a proper `where` statement will have you covered.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson distinct from each other

Comment: @Conduit Yeah, I figured this would be the cleanest approach, but I haven't been able to get the syntax right

Comment: @SeanSmyth Ok, then Gordon seems to have you covered below :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using SQL Server 2008 r2

Comment: As a rule of thumb, always add your DBMS to the tags - helps us craft queries with the proper functions and syntax. [tag:sql-server] in this instance.

Comment: @Conduit Sounds good, I'll do that for future posts

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson This isn't what I was asking.  Gordon Linoff misunderstood.

Comment: Potentially a duplicate question. I just answered a very similar question this afternoon. [See this link.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590090/sql-distinct-query-with-whole-record/26592268#26592268)

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected output based on that sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have no `NULL` values, you would just do the logic in the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from table t
where a <> b and a <> c and b <> c;
```

EDIT:

For your modified problem, the solution may be:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by a, b, c) as cnt
      from table t
     ) t
where cnt = 1;
```

Comment: +1 It should work but `number vs string` comparison fails? In general cross datatypes..

Comment: This isn't what I was going for.  What I meant was, I have columns a-g, and I want every row where the set a,b,c is distinct from every other a,b,c set

Answer (score 1):

Given the comment on Gordon's answer, I believe this should work for you:

```
select * 
from table as main
    inner join (
        select a, b, c, count(*)
        from table
        group by a, b, c
        having count(*) = 1
    ) as sub
        on main.a = sub.a
        and main.b = sub.b
        and main.c = sub.c
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use COUNT(), partitioning by a, b and c;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY a, b, c) cnt FROM mytable
)
SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f, g FROM cte WHERE cnt=1;
```

This will - for each row - count the number of rows that have the same a/b/c combination, and return the full rows that are "unique" (ie have a count of one)

Answer (score 0):

So in the end, the fix was simple.

```
select a, b, c, max(d) as d, max(e) as e, ...... max(g) as g into #temp
from MyTable
group by a, b, c
```